# I can't see the comments mentioned alongside the Blogger post

Tags: blogger, blog, comments

As you can see in the screenshot below, there are comments next to blog posts, but I can’t see them. What do I have to do to see them?

[image: i cant see the comments mentioned..]

Answer (score -1):

When you edit a post, in the options bar on the right hand side, have you got Show Comments selected?   if not, then choose it and republish.

Comment: yes..its already selected